# In Magento 2 how can i keep shipping address same as billing address ?

Tags: magento2, checkout, billing-address

I don't want to give choice to customer different shipping address than the billing address. 
I want user should  add billing address and it should be same for shipping. 
I don't want to give choice user to select different shipping address. 
Could any one just give me way to complete this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to remove shipping address, or want to auto filled ?

Comment: Yes actually shipping address should not be displayed there billing address should be taken as shipping address always.

Comment: you need lot of customization for this.. will back to you if got a solution  for this